# Kong FastApi connection

Tags: fastapi, kong

I am new to FastApi, and Kong API-Gateway!

I am trying to call fastAPI application from the Kong API gateway.

The fastAPI application is running perfectly, but when I try to access it from Kong (after adding it as a service and configuring a route for the service), it fails showing the following error:

```
Failed to load API definition. 
Fetch error
Not Found /openapi.json
```

The FastAPI code is as follows:

```
from typing import Union

from fastapi.openapi.docs import (
    get_redoc_html,
    get_swagger_ui_html,
    get_swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_html,
)

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

from application import predict, read_imagefile, explain#,read_model
app = FastAPI(
        title="XAI_FASTAPI",
        version=0.1
)
@app.post("/predict/image")
async def predict_api(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    extension = file.filename.split(".")[-1] in ("jpg", "jpeg", "png")
    if not extension:
        return "Image must be jpg or png format!"
    image = read_imagefile(await file.read())
    prediction = predict(image)
    return prediction


@app.get("/docs", include_in_schema=False)
async def custom_swagger_ui_html():
    return get_swagger_ui_html(
        openapi_url=app.openapi_url,
        title=app.title + " - Swagger UI",
        oauth2_redirect_url=app.swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url,
        swagger_js_url="/static/swagger-ui-bundle.js",
        swagger_css_url="/static/swagger-ui.css",
    )


@app.get(app.swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url, include_in_schema=False)
async def swagger_ui_redirect():
    return get_swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_html()
```

any idea, how I can fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please share Kong config

Comment: It's too much text, the post and comment placeholders can't handle it (3000max). If you may tell me a specific section, I can share it. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @VikGamov did you manage to see my comment :)

Comment: I'm interested in the section where you configure Kong upstream service with your app. Maybe paste to github gist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your openapi_url and docs_url correctly. This works in my case:

FastAPI:

```
def create_application() -> FastAPI:
    application = FastAPI(openapi_url="/building/openapi.json", docs_url="/building/docs")

    application.include_router(create_building.router, prefix="/building", tags=["building"])
    application.include_router(modify_building.router, prefix="/building", tags=["building"])
    application.include_router(get_building.router, prefix="/building", tags=["building"])
    application.include_router(get_buildings.router, prefix="/building", tags=["building"])
    application.include_router(remove_building.router, prefix="/building", tags=["building"])
    application.include_router(assign_users_to_building.router, prefix="/building", tags=["building"])
    return application


app = create_application()
```

kong.yml file:

```
_format_version: "3.0"
_transform: true

services:
  - name: building_service
    url: http://building_service/building
    routes:
    - name: building_service_route
      paths:
      - /building
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ignac96 for your answer, When I am trying your solution I find this error: "NameError: name 'create_building' is not defined"

Comment: 'create_building' is just example. You need to import your endpoint router function. More informations about routers: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/